# Hibernate sql query format in console

Tags: spring, hibernate, log4j

I'm trying to log the sql queries i'm calling from a .xml file. The problem i'm facing is that when i see the log, it's not well formatted. Also, i don't know why it appears repeated...

> [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
>   [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
>   [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@1f03fba0] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
>   [main] INFO org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.servicios.test.TestRestauranteManager.findProveedoresByIdRestaurante() throws com.servicios.util.exceptions.AlergenosException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
>   [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@436bd4df testClass = TestRestauranteManager, testInstance = com.servicios.test.TestRestauranteManager@6848a051, testMethod = findProveedoresByIdRestaurante@TestRestauranteManager, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@149b0577 testClass = TestRestauranteManager, locations = '{classpath:test-applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager@5740ff5e]; rollback [true]
>   select restaurant0_."ID_RESTAURANTE" as ID_RESTA1_4_0_, restaurant0_."DESCRIPCION" as DESCRIPC2_4_0_, restaurant0_."ID_CADENA_RESTAURANTE" as ID_CADEN3_4_0_ from "RESTAURANTE" restaurant0_ where restaurant0_."ID_RESTAURANTE"=?
>   Hibernate: select restaurant0_."ID_RESTAURANTE" as ID_RESTA1_4_0_, restaurant0_."DESCRIPCION" as DESCRIPC2_4_0_, restaurant0_."ID_CADENA_RESTAURANTE" as ID_CADEN3_4_0_ from "RESTAURANTE" restaurant0_ where restaurant0_."ID_RESTAURANTE"=?
>   binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]

I would like to have something like

> > [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper. [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper -
> >     Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper. [main] INFO
> >     org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager - Using
> >     DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@1f03fba0] of
> >     Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager [main] INFO
> >     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy
> >     method [public final void
> >     com.servicios.test.TestRestauranteManager.findProveedoresByIdRestaurante()
> >     throws com.servicios.util.exceptions.AlergenosException] because it is
> >     final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the
> >     target instance. [main] INFO
> >     org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext -
> >     Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@436bd4df
> >     testClass = TestRestauranteManager, testInstance =
> >     com.servicios.test.TestRestauranteManager@6848a051, testMethod =
> >     findProveedoresByIdRestaurante@TestRestauranteManager, testException =
> >     [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
> >     [MergedContextConfiguration@149b0577 testClass =
> >     TestRestauranteManager, locations =
> >     '{classpath:test-applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}',
> >     contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}',
> >     propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}',
> >     contextLoader =
> >     'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader',
> >     parent = [null]]]; transaction manager
> >     [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager@5740ff5e];
> >     Hibernate:  select 
> >                   p."DESCRIPCION" as "descripcion",
> >                   p."ID_PROVEEDOR" as "idProveedor"
>
> ```
>           from
>               "RESTAURANTE_PROVEEDOR" rp
>               inner join
>                   "PROVEEDOR" p 
>                       on rp."ID_PROVEEDOR" = p."ID_PROVEEDOR"
>           where 
>               rp."ID_RESTAURANTE" = ? binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
> ```

My log4j.properties is the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rootConsola.layout.ConversionPattern=(%d{dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss}) %-5p: %-40c{1} - %m%n
```

And in my ApplicationContext.xml I have this

```
...
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.servicios.vo"/>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:hibernate/queries/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 
...
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hibernate.format_sql` setting does not apply to Exception reasons when something happens and an Exception is thrown that includes a SQL fragment.

In other words, `hibernate.format_sql` only applies when Hibernate writes the SQL it's about to execute to the logs, not when it's included as part of some Exception reason.